# Encrypting Web.Config

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, encryption, web-config

Duplicate of [Encrypting config files for deployment .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559995/encrypting-config-files-for-deployment-net) and [Encrypting config files for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563717/encrypting-config-files-for-deployment)

---

What is the best approach and tools for encrypting information in web.config file?

Comment: a duplicate of what? comments like that should always come with a link :)

Comment: @Zeus, true, but the first two in the 'Related' box will do.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I'm voting it for closing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe there are two ways of doing this:

using aspnet_regiis using [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx) or [RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx), or [doing it programmatically](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=185&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

The programmatic way can be handy, particularly if you also like to encrypt app.config.

From my experiences of using this, if you write a custom configuration section, you have install the DLL containing the classes for that section into the GAC. For a project I was working I basically scripted the following approach:

- Copy config DLL to GAC.
- Perform encryption.
- Remove config DLL from GAC.

Chances are if you are just encrypting connection strings then this won't be a problem. You also need to be bear in mind whether you want to encrypt on a machine wide basis or to a specific user account- both options can be useful depending on your scenario. For simplicity I stuck to machine wide encryption. The links I have provided explain the merits of both approaches.

Comment: Yes @Richard making it machine wide makes more easy!

Comment: Hi RichardOD, my question is.. If doing it programmatically. When do I need to encrypt and decrypt the webconfig file? Check my post on this link --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614737/encrypt-decrypt-web-config

Comment: What is the point of doing this? Anyone can easily decrypt the connection strings just as easily as we can encrypt it.

Comment: @markthewizard1234 They keys used for encryption are machine-specific. So you would not be able to encrypt it unless you have access to the server. See https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config (paragraph Questions & Answers)

Comment: @markthewizard1234:  Anyone who has admin access to the server.

Answer (score 19):

Here are the commands to encrypt web.config file without any programming...

For encryption

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "Section" "Path exluding web.config"
```

For Decryption

```
aspnet_regiis -pdf "Section" "Path exluding web.config"
```

From this commands you can encrypt or decrypt all the section.

Comment: Don't put a trailing "\" on the end of the path either. It didn't work for me until I removed that.

Comment: And make sure to run with admin privileges.

Comment: Where to run this command, when I start cmd as administrator and run command it says `'aspnet_regiis' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` And when I go to the path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and open file `aspnet_regiis.exe` it auto closes. How can I run this command?

Comment: You can find the aspnet_regiis.exe at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`. Execute the aspnet_regis.exe inside of the windows command prompt  (cmd). You might use `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe" -pdf "Section" "Path exluding web.config"`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx

Comment: The blog mentions that IIS manager allows one to edit encrypted sections. But IIS 7 onwards this is not true. The runtime can decrypt the encrypted web.config but not the  IIS manager

Comment: Thanks @irwin very nice resource for further studying the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the aspnet_regiis tool in your framework directory:

```
                                        -- CONFIGURATION ENCRYPTION OPTIONS --

pe section            Encrypt the configuration section. Optional arguments:
                      [-prov provider] Use this provider to encrypt.
                      [-app virtual-path] Encrypt at this virtual path. Virtual path must begin with a forward slash.
                      If it is '/', then it refers to the root of the site. If -app is not specified, the root
                      web.config will be encrypted.
                      [-site site-name-or-ID] The site of the virtual path specified in -app. If not specified, the
                      default web site will be used.
                      [-location sub-path] Location sub path.
                      [-pkm] Encrypt/decrypt the machine.config instead of web.config.

pd section            Decrypt the configuration section. Optional arguments:
                      [-app virtual-path] Decrypt at this virtual path. Virtual path must begin with a forward slash.
                      If it is '/', then it refers to the root of the site. If -app is not specified, the root
                      web.config will be decrypted.
                      [-site site-name-or-ID] The site of the virtual path specified in -app. If not specified, the
                      default web site will be used.
                      [-location sub-path] Location sub path.
                      [-pkm] Encrypt/decrypt the machine.config instead of web.config.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should start from here, easy to follow, well explained step-by-step guide in MSDN: [How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Use the aspnet_regiis.exe Command-Line Tool**

You can also encrypt and decrypt sections in the Web.config file using the aspnet_regiis.exe command-line tool, which can be found in the %WINDOWSDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\version directory.

Look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043331/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx.