# What's the best approach in encrypting the entity framework connection string?

Tags: entity-framework, security, encryption, app-config

using the database first approach in Entity Framework, using the connection string stored in the app.config file, what would be the best approach in encrypting or hiding the connection string when deployed to production?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt connection string in app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting Web.Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075245/encrypting-web-config)

Answer (score 0):

Define the location of `config` File

```
Configuration config  = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

if you want to encrypt  `connectionStrings`

```
config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(Nothing);
```

you must be aware of app config portions

so if you want to encrypt `AppSettings`

```
config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(Nothing);
```

[image]